# SQL Strings that begin and end with Vowels - Looking for Shortcut

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a newbie question regarding SQL. Is it possible to query a column in a table for strings that begin and end with vowels. I understand I can do the following....

```
    SELECT ColumnName
    FROM Table
    WHERE ColumnName LIKE 'A%a' or 'E%a' or 'I%a' or 'O%a' or 'U%a' or
    'A%e' or 'E%e' or 'I%e' or 'O%e' or 'U%e'...........etc...........;
```

But it feels like there has to be a shortcut. I just don't know what it is.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `REGEXP`.

```
SELECT ColumnName
FROM Table
WHERE ColumnName REGEXP '^[aeiouAEIOU].*[aeiouAEIOU]$'
```

Answer (score 4):

One approach which is a bit more aethestically pleasing than your original query which does not use `REGEXP` would be to use `WHERE IN` along with `SUBSTRING()`:

```
SELECT ColumnName
FROM Table
WHERE LOWER(SUBSTRING(ColumnName, 1, 1)) IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u') AND
      LOWER(SUBSTRING(ColumnName, CHAR_LENGTH(ColumnName), 1)) IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
```

Comment: @Ollie, Just for educational purposes, could you try my query and let me know whether it works?

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen, Yes it did work in MySQL! Thank you!